# Convert all sheets in excel to Json with node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I’m trying to convert an excel into json.

Tried using “xls-to-json” npm package.

```
   node_xj = require("xls-to-json");
node_xj({
input: "Auto.xlsx",  // input xls 
output: "output.json", // output json 
sheet: "Login"  // specific sheetname 
}, function (err, result) {
if (err) {
    console.error(err);
} else {
    console.log(result);
}
});
```

Above code works fine to write all data in Login sheet to output.json file.
 I’m unable to figure out what changes I should do to read all sheets in the excel and convert it to one Json.

Or pass    values to   output: "output.json",  and    sheet: "Login"  dynamically so every sheet data is written into a different Json.
Tried :

1. passed    sheet: "Login",”Logout” and sheet:”Login,Logout”  .
2. Created a Json file, read values from it and passed it to

   input: jsonobj.input,  // input xls

   output:  jsonobj.output , // output json

   sheet: jsonobj.sheet // specific sheetname

This read the first value and then threw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another excel to json package "convert-excel-to-json" helped me achieve my objective.

```
var excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json');

var result = excelToJson({
sourceFile: 'Auto.xlsx',
header: {

    rows: 1 
},
columnToKey: {
   '*': '{{columnHeader}}'
}
});
```

Above code gave the JSON object.  Then used package "jsonfile" to write it into a json file.

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')

var file = 'output.json'

jsonfile.writeFile(file, result, function (err) {
console.error(err)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is removing blank value fields. WHich is a problem.

Comment: give some more descriptive ans.